# Extracting fields from JSON chatbot log and writing it into XLSX file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, chatbot

I have the below JSON file, from which i need to extract fields and write to an XLSX file

Its a chatbot conversation. I need to extract from bottom-up, meaning the chats are extracted in desceding order of thier timestamp

below are 2 examples,

**In example 1**

**User 1 says "Hi"**

**Bot replies with "Hi Good afternoon" with 2 buttons "A1 task and B1 task"**

---

**In  example 2**

**User 2 say "T market"**

**Bot replies with "market is good in france"**

Input Json

```
[
    {
        "document": {
            "$type": "abc",
            "From": {
                "$type": "aaa",
                "id": "123",
                "name": "buddy",
                "aadObjectId": null,
                "role": null
            },
            "To": {
                "$type": "abc",
                "id": "345",
                "name": "User1",
                "aadObjectId": "yyu5",
                "role": "User1"
            },
            "Text": null,
            "attchment": {
                "text": "Hi User1, Good Afternoon!! \n\n I can help you with",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "A1 task",
                        "value": "B1 task"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "b1 task",
                        "value": "b1 task"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "timestamp": "2020-02-13T08:10:32.9160151+00:00"
        }
    },

    {
        "document": {
            "$type": "iop",
            "From": {
                "$type": "jkl",
                "id": "984",
                "name": "User1",
                "aadObjectId": "jh56",
                "role": "User1"
            },
            "To": {
                "$type": "iopa",
                "id": "865",
                "name": "buddy",
                "aadObjectId": null,
                "role": null
            },
            "Text": "hi ",
            "attchment": null,
            "timestamp": "2020-02-13T08:10:32.9117352+00:00"
        }
    },



    {
        "document": {
            "$type": "pqr",
            "From": {
                "$type": "ppq",
                "id": "567",
                "name": "buddy",
                "aadObjectId": null,
                "role": null
            },
            "To": {
                "$type": "ppw",
                "id": "908",
                "name": "User2",
                "aadObjectId": "dd4",
                "role": "User2"
            },
            "Text": "Market in france is awesome",
            "attchment": null,
            "timestamp": "2020-02-13T07:50:43.4723205+00:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "document": {
            "$type": "hjk",
            "From": {
                "$type": "iop",
                "id": "098",
                "name": "User2",
                "aadObjectId": "ffr",
                "role": "User2"
            },
            "To": {
                "$type": "uioo",
                "id": "980",
                "name": "buddy",
                "aadObjectId": null,
                "role": null
            },
            "Text": "t markets",
            "attchment": null,
            "timestamp": "2020-02-13T07:50:43.4717092+00:00"
        }
    },
```

The output i'm trying is as below

```
            User          Utterances        Response

            User1         Hi                Hi Good afternoon 
                                            A1 B1      

            User2         T market          market is good in france
```

Comment: CSV and XLSX are completely different formats. CSV is a plain-old text file with commas. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. In any case you'll find a *lot* of questions asking how to create CSV or xlsx files, and the packages that can be used to do that (eg openpyxl). Same for parsing JSON (Pandas has a read_json). Or saving frames as xlsx  (to_excel) or csv (to_csv)

Comment: okay thanks. I would go with XLSX format. Please let me know how to go about it, since i'm new to this area

Comment: So am I. I googled `pandas csv` and `pandas json` to find all these. I've seen `openpyxl` in previous questions.  The links contain examples too. The *easy* way to find answers is to search for them. SO has a *lot* of answers already